# Combining multiple different Aframe codes

Tags: aframe

I want to know how to combine multiple different sequences of code onto one set of code, like making each section into an entity. We are a computer science class doing a large scale project where we had groups and made a section/wing of the school and now we are combining all of our wings to one.

we've tried making into an actual entity but it can't.

Some sort of merge command

Comment: Are these aframe components ? Loose js ? separate html files ? Any example (even simplified to three `<a-box>`es) where you show what's going on would be helpful

Comment: we are using neocities to type our code, the problem is is that we need to combine all 6 groups into one neocity bit of code, and to be able to move the six peices without having to move every single plane and having to rotate each plane, we have one group as the starting posistion 0,0 but since we all made a wing at that starting position we need to move it to connect correctly, we thought about just moving the positions and rotations but we figured out we would need to basically redo all the work we have already done. we want to make each bit of code go on one position code and one rotation

Comment: I didn't use neocities, but is grouping the wings an option, like in my anwser ?

Answer (score 0):

If You have trouble with multiple scenes, which need to be repositioned to match each other, you could try grouping them into parent entities

```
<a-entity id='one-wing' position='0 0 0'>
  <!--- Whole wing except light and camera ---!>
<a-entity>

<a-entity id='another-wing' position='15 0 15>
  <!--- another wing except light and camera ---!>
<a-entity>
```

This way you won't need to reposition and rotate every element - just the parent entities to match each other.

For example:

- [scene one](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lkoja3/)
- [scene two](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lkoja3/1)
- [combined](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lkoja3/2)

Comment: we found out how to... it was exactly that, and that exact code was what everyone else was telling me DIDN'T work... lord and behold... it works... sorry to bother you, thanks for the help